# Создание пользователя в APEX из PLSQL

Tags: oracle-apex

При попытке создать юзера по примеру

```
BEGIN
    FOR C1 IN (SELECT WORKSPACE_ID
                 FROM APEX_APPLICATIONS
                WHERE APPLICATION_ID = 4050)
    LOOP
        APEX_UTIL.SET_SECURITY_GROUP_ID (
            P_SECURITY_GROUP_ID   => C1.WORKSPACE_ID);
    END LOOP;
    
    APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER (
        P_USER_NAME                 => 'BOB',
        P_EMAIL_ADDRESS             => 'bob@bob.com',
        P_DEFAULT_SCHEMA            => 'OACADEMY_DB10',
        P_ALLOW_ACCESS_TO_SCHEMAS   => 'OACADEMY_DB10',
        P_WEB_PASSWORD              => 'change_me',
        P_DEVELOPER_PRIVS           =>
            'ADMIN:CREATE:DATA_LOADER:EDIT:HELP:MONITOR:SQL'); -- workspace administrator

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Ошибка

```
[Error] Execution (2: 1): **ORA-20987: APEX - Security Group ID (your workspace identity) is invalid. - Contact your application administrator.**
Details about this incident are available via debug id "78574".
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1064
ORA-06512:  at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1431
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY", line 3114
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.HTMLDB_UTIL", line 3075
ORA-06512: at line 8
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Workspace существует

```
APEX_UTIL.FIND_SECURITY_GROUP_ID (p_workspace=>'INTERNAL');
```

возвращает NULL

Comment: вы точно теплое с мягким не путаете? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-8C42A475-FB84-4134-BEB1-825FC4DFC3A8.htm#AEAPI124

Comment: да, вероятно :(
пробежался по всем wokrspace и для всех возвращает пусто
    VAL := APEX_UTIL.FIND_SECURITY_GROUP_ID (p_workspace=>C.WORKSPACE);
Возможно, что SECURITY_GROUP не задана?